# Hover Event in Javascript/PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

To give some Background information: I've got a php-function "showSystems" which extracts data from our CMDB and shows it in a Dropdown generated by the Codeigniter form helper "form_dropdown". So the dropdown contains the names of all our servers and when clicking on one, some other unrelevant functions show different kinds of information about that particular system.

What I want to achieve now is, when hovering over a system listed in the dropdown, that the description of that system is shown in a label under the list. When nothing is hovered, the label is hidden.

Something like:

```
Dropdown:
Server1
Server2  <-- hover over this
Server3

Label --> shows Description of Server2
```

How can I handle the mosehover-event in this generated dropdown using php/javascript?

Edit: So I give some more background-information, as it seems to have something to do with my technical setup.

The function, which produces the dropdown with the received data is written in a model of Codeigniter:

```
 <?php
 echo '<select class="minipanel" id="selectminipanel"  size="25" style="width: 100%" onchange="window.location = \''.site_url(CONTROLLER.'/showItem').'/\' + this.value;">';
         foreach($tmp as $key => $value):
                if ($active == $key){
                    echo '<option onmouseover="displayDescription(this)" onmouseout="hideLabel()" value="'.$key.'" server-description="'.$value[1].'" selected>'.$value[0].'</option>';
                } else {
                    echo '<option onmouseover="displayDescription(this)" onmouseout="hideLabel()" value="'.$key.'" server-description="'.$value[1].'">'.$value[0].'</option>';
                }
         endforeach;
 echo '</select>';
 ?>
```

The modul is loaded in a template via a view(which loads the model). The label is defined right after the codeigniter call:

```
 <?php $this->load->view("V".$this->name."/vMinipanel"); ?>
 <label id="description"></label>
```

The script is also written in this template's head section:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
 function displayDescription($ele) {
          var server_data = ele.server-description;
          document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = server_data;
 }
 function hideLabel() {
          document.getElementById('description').innerHTML ='';
 }
 </script>
```

So, why are the functions displayDescription and hideLabel not called?

Comment: If you can include jquery then it can be easily availabe with title="" tag in dropdown fields.

Comment: So how would I do this if I'm able to include Jquery? I just have no experience in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check and run below code:

```html
<a href="#" title="server 1 description">server 1</a><br>
<a href="#" title="server 2 description">server 2</a><br>
<a href="#" title="server 3 description">server 3</a>
```

Comment: funny how easy this would've been. Thank you.

Comment: yes its easy so I have commented above... thanks for accept and +1 :) @Fuerro

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="server 1 description">server 1</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="server 2 description">server 2</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="server 3 description">server 3</a>
```

just these lines of codes will work fine for you .

Comment: sadly, I'm not using bootstrap. Just php and javascript with the Codeigniter php-framework.

Comment: Then you should create a dynamic element and then show it on hover @fuerro

Comment: My Problem is, I can't get the hover event to work. I wanted to use onmouseover & onmouseout and call a jscript function like AnatPort suggested, but it seems like the function doesn't get called. How can I do your dynamic Element-thing?

Answer (score 0):

trigger an event on mouse over, and use the element's data-description to show the details:

```
<option onmouseover="displayDescription(this)" onmouseout="hideLabel()" data-server-description="your_description" id='1'>
Server1 
</option>

<script>
function displayDescription(ele) 
{
 // You can use the data-server-description attribute to catch the description
  var server_data = ele.data-server-description;

  // you can also use the ID to fetch the description if not embadded in as an html attribute
  var server_id = ele.id;

  document.getElementById('your_label_id').innerHTML = server_data;   
}

function hideLabel()
{
  document.getElementById('your_label_id').innerHTML =''; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: I just have to check if I can add parameters to each option then I'll try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: So I was able to set everything up, I've now got the 2 events in the options tag and the server description. How do I need to configure the Label?  `<label id="description"></label>`

would this already be enough?

Comment: give the label an ID, thats how you capture it and change its inner html. `<label id='your_label_id'></label>`

Comment: I made it exactly as you discribed, but it seems that the onmouseover does not call the jscript function. 

My Options each now look like this: `<option onmouseover="displayDescription(this)" onmouseout="hideLabel()" value="112073" server-description="Backup Server">server112073</option>`, where Value is the unique ID of each Database-record.